# How can I get a corresponding maximum and minimum id in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I am using MySQL to keep data for a large set of simulations I am running on an HPC cluster.  Each simulation has its own entry in a table, and there is a second table which keeps the simulation time step result data.  The time step result data table is quite large (tens to hundreds of millions of rows).  The tables look like this:

**Table: simulations**

```
id      descriptor  notes 
1       SIM1        notes here...
2       SIM2        SIM2 Notes...
...     ...         ...
8643    SIM8643     SIM8643 Notes...
```

**Table: simulations_ts**

```
id         simulation_id    step        data_value
1          1                1           0.05
2          1                2           0.051
...        ...              ...         ...
1983       1                1983        0.253
1984       2                1           0.043
...        ...              ...         ...
59345435   8643             2832        0.067
```

I would like to efficiently be able to return the following table:

```
simulation_id    first_ts_id     last_ts_id  num_steps
1                1               1983        1983
2                1984            2938434     2052
...              ...             ...         ...
8643             12835283        59345435    2832
```

I know I can perform a query like:

```
SELECT
   simulation_id
   MIN(step) AS first_step,
   MAX(step) AS last_step,
   COUNT(id) AS num_steps
FROM
   simulations_ts
GROUP BY
   simulation_id
ORDER BY
   simulation_id ASC
```

And that there are ways to do sub-queries to pull the corresponding id for one aggregate, but I have found no examples to pull the corresponding id for two aggregate functions.  Is this possible to do in a single query in an efficient way, or am I better off just stepping through and doing a min lookup and max lookup separately?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about `pull the corresponding id for two aggregate functions` with an example?

Comment: @sarwar026: See the "I would like to efficiently be able to return the following table" above.  I am looking to pull the simulation_ts.id that corresponds to the maximum simulation_ts.step, and minimum simulation_ts.step for a grouped simulation_ts.simulation_id (I hope that clarifies it a bit)

Comment: Doesn't your query do that? Is it just not efficient enough? What indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: What's the relevance of the `simulations` table? Your query doesn't use it.

Comment: @Barmar No.  My query pulls the min and max simulation_ts.step.  I need the simulation_ts.id that corresponds to the min and max simulation_ts.step (so that I can access the corresponding data).  As for indexes, just the auto-increment id, and simulation_id.  As for the relevance of simulations, it contains more data about the overall sim.  I guess it isn't fully relevant to this question.

Comment: I think, you have to go for `sub-query`. Let us see others elegant solution from the experts!

Comment: This seems like a fairly run-of-the-mill groupwise-max problem but anyway, consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT simulation_id, first.id as first_ts_id, last.id as last_ts_id, num_steps
FROM (SELECT simulation_id, MIN(step) minstep, MAX(step) maxstep, COUNT(*) num_steps
      FROM simulations_ts
      GROUP BY simulation_id) AS g
JOIN simulations_ts first ON first.simulation_id = g.simulation_id AND first.step = g.minstep
JOIN simulations_ts last ON last.simulation_id = g.simulation_id AND last.step = g.maxstep
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after.  Note that I'm only displaying the id column from the `first_dim_id` and `last_dim_id` aliases of simulations_ts, but you could of course display other columns from that table.

```
SELECT
   main.simulation_id,
   first_step,
   first_sim.id as first_sim_id,
   last_step,
   last_sim.id as last_sim_id
FROM
   (SELECT
       simulation_id,
       MIN(step) AS first_step,
       MAX(step) AS last_step,
       COUNT(id) AS num_steps
    FROM
       simulations_ts
    GROUP BY
       simulation_id) as main
    JOIN simulations_ts first_sim
         ON main.simulation_id = first_sim.simulation_id
            AND main.first_step = first_sim.step
    JOIN simulations_ts last_sim
         ON main.simulation_id = first_sim.simulation_id
            AND main.last_step = last_sim.step
```

I start with your original query, then simply join it back to `simulations_ts` on the sim id and min/max step.